# Swift | Working with Audio messages from Whatsapp

Tags: ios, swift

I hope you are well today!

I'm trying to create a very simple application which has a minor Social Extension.
When user shares an audio message to my app, I want my app to detects if it's an audio or not. It will work only for audio attachment but I can't make it happen.
For example, if I change 'kUTTypeAudio' to 'kUTTypeImage' and I'm trying to share an image to my app - it works. It detects the image type, but with Audio message it doesn't work.
In my app, I don't need the ShareView UI with the post button and everything. I That's the reason I'm canceling the View and just show an alert with a message to the user.

My questions are:
1. How can I detect an audio message from Whatsapp?
2. Next, How can I work with this audio message? I need to get it to a variable and then make my needs or what?
Thanks guys!

This is my ShareViewController.swift:

```
//
// ShareViewController.swift
// Get Message
//
// Created by Tom Luz on 12/11/2017.
// Copyright © 2017 Tom Luz. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices
class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {
    override func isContentValid() - > Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
        return false
    }
    override func didSelectPost() {
        // This is called after the user selects Post. Do the upload of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments.
        // Inform the host that we're done, so it un-blocks its UI. Note: Alternatively you could call super's -didSelectPost, which will similarly complete the extension context.
        self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
    }
    override func configurationItems() - > [Any] !{
        // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
        return []
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let contentType = kUTTypeAudio as String
        if let content = extensionContext ? .inputItems.first as ? NSExtensionItem,
            let contentProvider = content.attachments ? .first as ? NSItemProvider,
                contentProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(contentType) {
                    contentProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: contentType, options: nil) {
                        (data, error) in
                        let data = data as ? String
                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Words Are Better", message: data, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: self.cancelShareExtension))
                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
        else {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Words Are Better", message: "Not OK", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: self.cancelShareExtension))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    func cancelShareExtension(alert: UIAlertAction) {
        cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems okay. Try using kUTTypeAudiovisualContent instead of kUTTypeAudio and see if it triggers. Then we can try debugging from there.

Comment: It doesn't work, still get "Not OK"

Comment: @nanibir UP UP UP :) Can't fix this \=